# Magento 2.1.2 super slow

Tags: magento2, performance, installation, magento-2.1.2, vagrant

I install Magento 2.1.2 on a vagrant powered virtualbox with Ubuntu 16.04 64bit with 4GB RAM and 2 processors on a MacBook Pro 2015 with 16GB RAM and 2,9 Ghz Intel Core i5.
I have faked a domain https://www.testing.com for that box.
Magento is installed in a subdirectory https://www.testing.com/shop

On the machine itself the folder structure in short is:

```
/var/www/share/testing.com/htdocs (webroot)                  -> symlink to /var/www/share/testing.com/cms/current
/var/www/share/testing.com/cms/current                       -> symlink to /var/www/share/testing.com/cms/deploy/<datetime>/htdocs
/var/www/share/testing.com/cms/deploy/<datetime>/htdocs/shop -> symlink to /var/www/share/testing.com/shop/current
/var/www/share/testing.com/shop/current                      -> symlink to /var/www/share/testing.com/shop/deploy/<datetime>/htdocs
```

Already the installation is super slow. With the web wizard it fails to install as it gets stuck at installing the user configuration.

As adviced in other tickets I thus install it via composer and commandline. But also on the commandline "generating autoload files" takes >5min.

After the successful installation the whole bare shop is super slow. Pages take >1min to load. No difference in the backend.
Deploying static files does not change the behavior.

Changing to production mode is impossible as it generates seemingly infinitely.
I let the script run for about 3 hours until I stopped it.

One other thing that is strange is that all scripts run with "php bin/magento ..." take a lot of time to "start".
I send the command and then it takes about a minute to actually produce the first output. After it produces the first output the scripts seem to run at a fair speed (except the one for switching to production mode).
This happens for everything I do. Like clearing/flushing caches, deploying static files, installing and so on.

Maybe there is a problem with the autoloader?
Could that time be the time the autoloader indexes all needed files?

Well anyway the question is: why is my Magento slow? What else could I do find the reason?

*edit*

This is the install command I use:

```
php current/bin/magento setup:install --admin-firstname=xxx --admin-lastname=xxx --admin-email=xxx --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin1234 --base-url=https://www.testing.com/shop/ --backend-frontname=xxx --db-host=localhost --db-name=xxx --db-user=xxx --db-password=xxx --language=de_DE --currency=EUR --timezone=Europe/Berlin --use-rewrites=0 --use-secure=1 --base-url-secure=https://www.testing.com/shop/ --use-secure-admin=1 --admin-use-security-key=1 --session-save=db --cleanup-database
```

I tried with use-rewrite on and off. No change in behaviour though.

*edit2*

Here is a har file of the second call of the frontend:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/318d183e1be5d4ea5b674654c8fc5f0e

You can view it in http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/

Also I attached a htop screenshot while loading the admin backend.
[image]

And one other thing I found strange is the admin url:
`https://www.testing.com/shop/index.php/zoo/admin/index/index/key/<key/`

Why is are there 2 `index` in there?

Comment: btw. the scripts (aka website) running in the webroot or `/var/www/share/testing.com/cms/current/` run smooth as expected

Comment: Do you install magento on VirtualBox shared folder?

Comment: I'm not really sure how it works on detail. But I think so. It has never been a problem with any application so far though.

Comment: try add  type: "nfs" to  config.vm.synced_folde .., like config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", and reload vm (vagrant halt && vagrant up)

Comment: I use puphpet to setup the machine. I just checked at least it allows to set the type to nfs. I can't check now but I'll confirm later what is used in my setup.

Comment: I copied the configuration from a non unix system and it did not have the nfs option. I activated it and the shop is much faster now.
Could you post this as answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox shared folder is slow, and Magento use file caches by default, it has many classes and resources in file system, it's why it may be slow.

Try add type: "nfs" to config.vm.synced_folde .., like config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "nfs", and reload vm (vagrant halt && vagrant up)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure magento mode should be production, then host the magento from the pub folder not from the root folder. It will make your magento super fast.